# How to save route drawn in MKMapView as Core data?

Tags: save, mkmapview, swiftui

[image]

I drew a route on the `MKMapView`.
I saved the location datas to draw the route.
Stored location datas is tens of megabytes per day.
So I'm trying to reduce the data that's stored, and all I need is a map with the route of the past.

What is simple data other than hundreds of stored location datas to make the route appear as shown in the screenshot?

Comment: @Rob Thx for answer ‘MKMapSnapshotter’, and ur question is yes of my answer. Just route data in one day is tens of megabytes. update location is so many if I go around a lot. Above shot is small part of entire route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MKMapSnapshotter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapsnapshotter). Unfortunately, you’ll have to `stroke` your path manually, using [`point(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapsnapshotter/snapshot/1452523-point) to convert the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` into `CGPoint` within the `MKMapSnapshotter.Snapshot`:

```
let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
options.region = mapView.region
options.size = mapView.bounds.size

MKMapSnapshotter(options: options).start { snapshot, _ in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

    let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: options.size).image { _ in
        snapshot.image.draw(at: .zero)

        let count = route.polyline.pointCount
        let points = route.polyline.points()
        guard count > 1 else { return }

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: snapshot.point(for: points[0].coordinate))
        for i in 1 ..< count {
            path.addLine(to: snapshot.point(for: points[i].coordinate))
        }

        path.lineWidth = 4
        path.lineCapStyle = .round
        path.lineJoinStyle = .round
        UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.75).setStroke()

        path.stroke()
    }

    guard let data = image.pngData() else { return }

    // you can now write this `data` to persistent storage
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Now, the above is obviously just stroking the `route.polyline` associated with a `MKDirections` result in a single `UIBezierPath`, and you’re going to be iterating through your model, presumably stroking each of those different colored portions in individual `UIBezierPath`, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.